# App install failed but files are still filling up the phone

Tags: applications, internal-storage, installation, system-error

I installed the game N.O.V.A.3. When it was finished, I got an error message saying that the install failed. However, the 1.7GB that the game required are still missing from my phone. The app does not show upp on "Application Manager. Since I used the refund button in Play Store, it doesent show there either.

My memory on the phone right now is 300mb. So, I can't install the game again or something like that. The phone is not rooted, and I won't root it since it breaks the warranty :( Is there any chance that I can remove the files without having to restore the entire phone?

I've also checked the folders when hooking up the phone to the computer. It's not there.
My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini.

I'd be very grateful if someone helped me!

*SOLVED*

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Answer from the comments, as OP/answerer disappeared:</sup>

Browsing the device from a connected computer, those files could be found and deleted.

---

Unfortunately, Rick missed to say where he found them. So I include some clues where they *might* have been, together with some reason. These items include places to look for left-overs following even a successfull uninstall:

- `/data/local`: That's where *Google Play* downloads `.apk` files to before installing them. As this directory also is accessible "publically", this is the most likely place for the OP's case.
- `/data/data/<package_name>`: unlikely, as it requires root for the user being able to access it – but that would have been the place the app would be installed in
- `<sdcard>/Android/data/<package_name>`: another candidate, again unlikely: while publically accessible, data here are usually placed by the app itself. Not being successfully installed, and neither turning up in the app drawer, the user couldn't start the app – so it couldn't place stuff here.
- `<sdcard>/<some directory>`: same as previous point. Some apps place stuff in different places, which then does not get cleaned-up automatically on uninstall.