# App not installed orphaned files

Tags: installation, apk, 4.3-jelly-bean

When an app attempts an installation, but results in "app not installed", do orphaned files still exist, or does android remove all traces of that App. I am running JB 4.3 stock on the Nexus 4

In other words if it doesnt show up in the "manage apps", it shouldnt exist in /data/apps

Comment: You might want to check: [App install failed but files are still filling up the phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36470/16575)